# Select Vertex based on edge property

Tags: azure, gremlin, tinkerpop3, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a complex scenario. So i tried to create a sample of it as below.

```
g.AddV('class').property('id','1').property('name','class1').AddE('roster').to(g.AddV('student').property('id','11').property('name','student1'))
g.AddV('class').property('id','2').property('name','class2').AddE('roster').to(g.AddV('student').property('id','22').property('name','student2'))
g.AddV('class').property('id','3').property('name','class3').AddE('roster').to(g.AddV('student').property('id','33').property('name','student3'))
g.AddV('class4').property('id','4').property('name','class4').AddE('roster').to(g.V('11'))
g.V('11').AddE('logs').property('class_id','1').to(g.AddV('log').property('id','111').property('name','log1'))
```

you may have observed that `student1` belongs to 2 classes (class1 and class4). And `student1` writes a log `log1` in `class1`. But If i run this query `g.V('111').as('l').in().as('s').in().as('c').project('log','student','class').by(select('l').by('name')).by(select('s').by('name')).by(select('c').by('name'))`

It returns duplicate data as shown below.

```
[
  {
    "log": "log1",
    "student": "student1",
    "class": "class1"
  },
  {
    "log": "log1",
    "student": "student1",
    "class": "class4"
  }
]
```

The expected behaviour is to return only log from class1. To achieve this i added a property `class_id` to the `logs` edge but not sure how to apply the condition to return deduplicated result i.e returns logs belonging to same class.

Any help with the query is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the student by an edge property you can use `where`:

```
g.V().has('name', 'log1').as('l').
  inE().as('e').outV().as('s').
  in().where(eq('e')).by('class_id').as('c').
  project('log', 'student', 'class').
    by(select('l').by('name')).
    by(select('s').
      by('name')).
    by(select('c').by('name'))
```

Note that I split your first `in` step so I could use the edge property

example:
https://gremlify.com/3q

Comment: since you're using step labels you can rename them to the keys in `project()` then convert the `project()` to `select('log', 'student', 'class').by('name')` - a bit less wordy and more readable